# Why is my rotated object resetting its rotation position after dragging into a new position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transform, css-transforms, moveable

I have a moveable-react component that is draggable and rotateable. If I rotate the object it rotates as expected but when I drag it (after rotating it) it resets to its original rotation angle.

Here are the onDrag and onRotate functions:

```
onDrag={({ target, beforeTranslate }) => {
  target.style.transform = `translate(${beforeTranslate[0]}px, ${beforeTranslate[1]}px)`;
}}
onRotate={({ target, transform }) => {
  target.style.transform = transform;
}}
```

This is what it looks like after being rotated:

[image: After rotation]

This is what it looks like after it is dragged to a new position (rotation has been reset):

[image: Notice the rotation has reset]

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-aryabhata-g8s749?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-babycat-cioh5u?file=/src/App.js)
When you are dragging you are not taking into account the rotation fixed that

Now when you rotate saving the rotating angle and using it while dragging